# Find third parent from a parent-child in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>
  <div> 
    <div class="one">child of 1 st Div</div>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <div class="two'>child of 2 st Div</div>
  </div>
  <div> 
    <div class="three">child of 3 st Div</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Here what I want to do is on clicking the div with **class="one"** I want to change the content of the third **div** where **class="three"**

Comment: In your jquery code, `$(".three").on('click', function() { $(".one"}.doStuff})`

Comment: ...so where is your jquery try?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error here : `<div class="two'>` it should be this :  `<div class="two">`

For the script, there are many way to do it, here is one :

```
$(function(){
    $('.one').click(function(){
      $('.three').text('hey');
    });
});
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/v0rtqkxn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you can attach a `click event` handler to a jQuery object using the `click` method. You select an element using the global jQuery function (usually `jQuery` or `$`). To select an element with a specific class, prepend `.` to the class.

```
$('.one').click(function(event) {
    // this function will be fired when the div with class `one` is clicked 

    var $three = $('.three');
    // $three is now a jQuery object representing the div 
    // DOM element with the class `three`

    // your code here     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your code you should correct your code for `class = "two"`. In order to select a div use jquery `.on()` event handler.

`$('selector').on('click',callback());`

Refer to the following code.

```
$('.one').on('click',function(){
  $('.three').addClass('changeColor');
})
```

I have also created a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/58kng68a/